# Sprockets::FileNotFound when using select2 gem with Rails 3.2.8

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, jquery-select2, sprockets, select2-rails

I am trying to test a sample Rails app to use [select2 gem](http://ivaynberg.github.io/select2/). I have install the gem following [select2-rails](https://github.com/argerim/select2-rails).

But, unfortunately I am getting the following error :

```
Sprockets::FileNotFound in Home#index

Showing /Users/Rakib/Desktop/Development/TEST_PROJECTS/selecttest/app/views/layouts/application.html.erb where line #5 raised:

couldn't find file 'select2'
  (in /Users/Rakib/Desktop/Development/TEST_PROJECTS/selecttest/app/assets/stylesheets/application.css:14)
Extracted source (around line #5):

2: <html>
3: <head>
4:   <title>Selecttest</title>
5:   <%= stylesheet_link_tag    "application", :media => "all" %>
6:   <%= javascript_include_tag "application" %>
7:   <%= csrf_meta_tags %>
8: </head>
Rails.root: /Users/Rakib/Desktop/Development/TEST_PROJECTS/selecttest
```

My Gemfile is :

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'

gem 'rails', '3.2.8'
gem 'sqlite3'

group :assets do
  gem 'sass-rails',   '~> 3.2.3'
  gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 3.2.1'
  gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.0.3'
end

gem 'jquery-rails'
gem 'jquery-rails'
gem "select2-rails"
```

**application.js** is :

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require select2
//= require_tree .
```

**application.css** is :

```
 *= require_self
 *= require_tree .
 *= require select2
```

What I am missing here ?

Comment: I'm guessing the server needs to be restarted. Were you able to resolve the issue this way?

Comment: In my case - I mistakenly installed gem "select2-rails" in not working  rvm of my project

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I met the same problem. Problem solved by restarting the server.

Comment: I feel such noob in rails.